# Yii2, Select2, Optgroup with Ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, yii-extensions

I'm using `Yii2` with `Select 2`. I've tried to use examples with optgroup, loaded from ajax. Browser sents requests, but doesn't show me anything when I trying to print.
Code is below.

```
<?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'cycle',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'multiple' => true,
             'ajax' => [
                 'url' => Url::to(['films-json/cycle-channel']),
                 'dataType' => 'json',
                 'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
             ],
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Cycle-channel action returns 100% working json. When I tried to use id as a static one (code below), it was working. But I need dynamic search.

```
<?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'cycle',
        'data' => FilmsJsonController::actionCycleChannel(''),
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'multiple' => true,
        ]
    ]);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you haven't told the widget to do anything with the returned data from your server. You need to add something like this to your plugin options;

```
'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(city) { return city.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (city) { return city.text; }'),
```

you will obviously need to change city.text to whatever text you want displayed in the select dropdown.

The controller need to return json data in the format expected by the plugin. The codumentation shows something like this;

```
public function actionSearch($q = null, $id = null) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
        if (!is_null($q)) {
            $query = new Query;
            $query->select('id, title AS text')
                    ->from('city')
                    ->where(['like', 'title', $q])
                    ->limit(20);
            $command = $query->createCommand();
            $data = $command->queryAll();
            $out['results'] = array_values($data);
        } elseif ($id > 0) {
            $out['results'] = ['id' => $id, 'text' => City::find($id)->title];
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

See [the documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax) for more examples

Comment: I've tried to use templates, but it closes dropdown instantly, after showing 'templateSelection' return for a moment. If I just use static "data" parameter, it works perfectly. I'm using json like this: {"Gr1":{"1":"Element1","6":"Element6"},"Gr2":{"3":"Element3"},"Gr3":{"2":"Element2","5":"Element5"},"Gr4":{"4":"Element4"}}

Comment: Ah, there is your problem, you json data need to be in the form expected by the plugin. you've called the data Gr!, Gr2 etc. The json need to be just 'results', then an array if ids and text. I've updated my answer to include the required data format.